# need help in merging questions with the answer

Tags: java

I'm creating a calculator which has to work out expressions like (12.0 + 10.0) * 3.0
so far i have created the sub classes according to each mathematical operation.

for example:

Addition. java

```
class Addition extends ArithmeticExpression {
    Addition(double value1, double value2) {
        result = value1 + value2;
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }
    public Addition( ArithmeticExpression an,double num2) {
        value1 = an.evaluate();
        value2 = num2;
        result1 = value1 + value2;
    }
    public double evaluate1() {
        System.out.println("Arbitrary Answer Is");
        return result1;
    }
    public double display1() {
        System.out.println("Arbitrary Question Is");
        System.out.println( "(" + value1 + "+"  + value2 + ")" + " =" + result1);
        return result1;
    }
    public double display() {
        System.out.println("Addition Question Is");
        System.out.println(value1 + " + "+ value2);
        return result;
    }
    public double evaluate() {
        System.out.println("Addition Answer Is");
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And another for the multiplication which is similar to that but multiplies in stead of adding.
i then created a class for the question i am answering the class is below.
Arbitrary.java

```
public class arbitrary {
    public Arbitrary() {
           Addition arbitrary1 = new Addition(12.0,10.0);
           arbitrary1.display1();
           Multiplication arbitrary2 = new Multiplication(arbitrary1,3.0);
           arbitrary2.display2();
    }
}
```

when it displays the answer it displays:

```
Arbitrary Question Is
(12.0+10.0) =0.0
Addition Answer Is
22.0
Arbitrary Question Is
(22.0*3.0) = 66.0
```

any suggestions on how i can print out the original question next to the answer?

Comment: Not without seeing the code...

Comment: can you be more specific? what do you mean by merge? what is the required, formatted output?

Comment: At the moment you haven't really described *what* you're trying to do, your code doesn't show *how* you're attempting it and you give no indication of where you're currently failing.  Re-read your question from the perspective of a total stranger and think if it makes sense on its own.

Comment: Do you mean "not put a newline between my printouts" when you say "merge"? What output would you _like_ it to show?

Comment: basically it should display (12.0+10.0) *3.0 = 66.0

Answer (score 2):

you can create a method that return the addition like

```
   long val=arbitrary1.display1();
```

store value of display1() in a variable and pass the value of variable in the

```
    Multiplication arbitrary2 = new Multiplication(val,3.0);
```